# # is appearing in the url only in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I have some links that look like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Receiving", "Index", "Receiving")
```

when using IE and clicking on this link it is adding a # in the url
this is what appears in the url after following the link

```
http://localhost:47547/#/Receiving
```

the view loads fine. but the problem is the form on this view does not work nothing happens.

if I type in the URL manually and remove the # everything works as expected including the form

Where is this # coming from and how do I stop it?

It does not appear when using any other browser and the form works fine on those browsers.

Update: I failed to mention I am using jQuery mobile on this site, It didn't occur to me that this could be causing some issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you sure there is not a javascript creating it?

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile? Looks like typical ajax navigation hash url.

Comment: Yes now that you ask i am using jqeury mobile, dont tell me it is adding the # ?

Comment: Yes, give the [ajax navigation docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) a good read.

Comment: @jrummell. thanks! if you want to put that down as an answer I will gladly accept your answer. I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: No problem. I added an answer with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how jQuery Mobile handles ajax navigation. You can read about it in the [Ajax, hashes & history](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) section of the docs.

> By default all navigation within jQuery Mobile is based on changes and
>   updates to location.hash. Whenever possible, page changes will use a
>   smooth transition between the current "page" and the next, whether it
>   is either already present in the DOM, or is automatically loaded via
>   Ajax.
>
> Hash values created by jQuery Mobile are normalized as full paths
>   relative to the URL of the first "real" page that was loaded. The hash
>   is always maintained as a valid URL, so any "page" in jQuery Mobile
>   can be bookmarked or referenced in a link. To retrieve a
>   non-hash-based URL, simply remove the # from the address and refresh
>   the page.